# Is there a way to display more than 5 items in a Bar Char List Card on an Overviewpage?

Tags: sapui5

For my use case I am in need of an Overview page to display several cards.

One of the cards I wish to display, is a Bar Chart List Card to visualize how many tasks I have for each Category.

The problem is that I have around 20 to 30 categories and the [FIORI-guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/overview-page-list-cards/#bar-chart-list-card) say that we shouldn't add more than 5 bar chart list items to a card.

I was wondering if this is just a guideline or if this is really a rule AND if any one has an alternative solution which is conform with the guidelines.

Thanks in advance for the advices.

Comment: The guidelines are there to guide you, just as the name suggests. They are best prectices that you should follow. Noone will hunt you down for not caring about them though.

Comment: True, but I'm afraid that it will break the look and/or navigation functionality of the card if I would include all 30 Categories. Any experience with it by any chanse?

Comment: I had that limitation and the only way I could managed that was by asking the user to change the tile size manually

Comment: @fabiopagoti did you stick to that solution or you came up with a work-around? Something tells me that this won't suffice for my users :)

Comment: I could not create any work-around for that. And unfortunately this piece of UI5 is not open source

Comment: how about a costom control? extent the card control